# Replace $request->all() with only non empty form fields

Tags: laravel

is it possible to replace $request->all() in the below line with only fields that are not empty in submitted form.

```
$product = Product::create($request->all());
```

when some form fields are empty,  the query generated is something like

```
insert into `products` (`name`, `companyname`, `ip`, `host`, `status`, `language`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (efesar, ewrewrewre, , , , , 2018-04-18 10:29:11, 2018-04-18 10:29:11))
```

And that's returning error.

Answer (score 2):

This would get you only the fields with values:

```
$data = collect($request->all())->filter()->toArray();
$product = Product::create($data);
```

But you should get from the request only the fields which are appropriate for your **Product** model or better yet, add validation for them. Depending on what you need, you might have to change some your table fields to be nullable to be able to save empty fields.

Answer (score 1):

Its not a problem to submit null fields. Just make them nullable in migration file:

```
$table->string('ip')->nullable();
$table->string('host')->nullable();
$table->string('status')->nullable();
$table->string('language')->nullable();
```